# Removing grayscale in HTML in website header image

Tags: css, grayscale

I am not HTML knowledgeable AT ALL. My post here is about an issue concerning the HTML in this website I'm creating   http://testingthistemplate.weebly.com/

I'm just trying to remove the grayscale code I am using in a Weebly website header. Nobody at Weebly or the Weebly support community is responding to my question. I don't know what to do. All I want is my website headers (they come from a Weebly template) to show the header images (they're mine, that I upload) in their normal color, not black and white.

I would really, really appreciate any help in editing this code below and posting it back up for me to copy. Sorry for the trouble. Thank you!!!!!

```
body {            

height: 100%;         

font-size: 15px;     

font-family: 'Cabin', Arial, sans-serif;        

line-height: 1;             

background: #2e2e2e;             

color: #818181;       

padding: 0 !important;         

margin: 0 !important;         

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;         

-moz-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;         

-o-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;         

-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#wrapper .wsite-background {
   filter : none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this CSS in `main_style.css` stylesheet:

```
#wrapper .wsite-background {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: transparent;z-index: 10;
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
}
```

Notice `-moz-filter`, `-ms-filter`, `-o-filter`, and `filter` settings? Remove those.

Answer (score 0):

Try and search through a `main_style.css` file or something with a `.css` extension. Ten find a section with this name: `#wrapper .wsite-background`. Change the following:

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: gray;
```

to

```
-webkit-filter: none;
-moz-filter: none;
-ms-filter: none;
-o-filter: none;
filter: none;
filter: none;
```